# how to display JSON output fetched from the oracle database with line breaks

Tags: php, jquery, newline

I have  an HTML page which is has one user input and one button. After clicking on the button, we can fetch other data related to that user from oracle database. i have defined my code in a seperate php page( index2.php ) which looks like below:-

```
<?php
class logAgent
{
    const CONFIG_FILENAME = "data_config.ini";

    private $_dbConn;
    private $_config;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_loadConfig();


        $this->_dbConn = oci_connect($this->_config['db_usrnm'],
            $this->_config['db_pwd'],
            $this->_config['hostnm_sid']);
    }
    private function _loadConfig()
    {
        // Loads config
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . self::CONFIG_FILENAME;
        $this->_config = parse_ini_file($path) ;
    }
    public function fetchLogs() {
        $userid =$_POST["userid"];
        $sql = "SELECT REQUEST_TIME,WORKFLOW_NAME,EVENT_MESSAGE
                            FROM AUTH_LOGS WHERE USERID = '".$userid."'";
        //Preparing an Oracle statement for execution
        $statement = oci_parse($this->_dbConn, $sql);

        //Executing statement
        oci_execute($statement);
        $json_array = array(); 

        while (($row = oci_fetch_row($statement)) != false) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            $json_array[] = $row; 
        }
            echo json_encode($json_array);
    }

}
    $logAgent = new logAgent();
    $logAgent->fetchLogs();
?>
```

I am doing this using asynchronous post method my defining a javascript file(script.js)

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybtn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
  var userid = $("#userid").val();
  
        //$.post("index2.php", {"userid" : userid})
  
  var posting = $.post( 'index2.php', {"userid" : userid}); 
  posting.done(function( res ) { 
   
   var response = $.parseJSON(res);
   $('#rawResponse').text(response); 
  }); 

    });
})
```

I have many data for one user. And output display looks like:
03-SEP-18,softOtpCheck,OTP check passed,03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,03-SEP-18,oamAuth,OAM context cookie collected.,03-SEP-18,softOtpCheck,OTP check passed,03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,03-SEP-18,oamAuth,OAM context cookie collected.

But i want it as :

03-SEP-18,softOtpCheck,OTP check passed,

03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,

03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,

03-SEP-18,oamAuth,OAM context cookie collected.,

03-SEP-18,softOtpCheck,OTP check passed,

03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,

03-SEP-18,createAuthenticatedSession,yoya session Created.,

03-SEP-18,oamAuth,OAM context cookie collected.

How can i display my output in a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to change

```
$('#rawResponse').text(response);
```

to

```
$('#rawResponse').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2) + '</pre>);
```

See [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and the enclosing `pre` tags will display the return value nicely.
Alternatively you could also put it into a `textarea`, it will also display the newlines properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo the json data, you can returns prettified data with newline characters using JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

```
echo json_encode($json_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: I tried this already but it is throwing error in my script. Can i change something in my script ?

Comment: @ssnone can you mention what kind of error do you see ?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1905
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (script.js:9)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @ssnone I have updated my answer, hopefully it helps